# Use Tensorflow2 saved model for object detection

Tags: tensorflow

im quite new to object detection but i managed to train my first Tensorflow custom model yesterday. I think it worked fine besides some warnings, at least i got my exported_model folder with checkpoint, saved model and pipeline.config. I built it with exporter_main_v2.py from Tensorflow. I just loaded some images of deers and want to try to detect some on different pictures.
That's what i would like to test now, but i dont know how. I already did an object detection tutorial with pre trained models and it worked fine. I tried to just replace config_file_path, saved_model_path and image_path with the paths linking to my exported model but it didnt work:

```
error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_io.cpp:42: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param). Failed to parse GraphDef file: D:\VSCode\Machine_Learning_Tests\Tensorflow\workspace\exported_models\first_model\saved_model\saved_model.pb in function 'cv::dnn::ReadTFNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie'
```

There are endless tutorials on how to train custom detection but i cant find a good explanation how to manually test my exported model.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I need to know how to build a script where i can import a model i saved with Tensorflow exporter_main_v2.py and an image i want to test this model on and get a result, either in text or with rectangels in picture. Seeing many tutorials but none works for me with a model i saved with Tensorflow exporter_main_v2.py

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to have a python script where i can load my model and then use object detection with this model on an image the script can read. But i dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like you have a model saved as `.pb`. If you want to do inference you can write something like this:

```
# load the model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(my_model_dir)

prediction = model.predict(x=x_test, ...)
```

You'll have to set `x` which is the only mandatory argument. It is your test dataset (the images you want to obtain predictions from). Also, `predict` is useful when you have a great amount of images to predict. It handles the prediction in a batched way, avoiding filling up the memory. If you have just a few you can use directly the `__call__()` method of your model, like this:

```
prediction = model(x_test, training=False)
```

More about prediction can be found at the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict).

Comment: I just want to read an image (a deer in forest) and load my model (saved tf2) and then want to "predict the image" with the model. Im not deep into TF2 yet so i dont understand how the background processes work.
Your answer comes close i guess, but i used 'model = tf.saved_model.load()' and get following error:




ValueError: Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:
  inputs: (
    [[[ 66  71  50]
  [ 66  71  50]
  [ 66  71  50]
  ...

 ...

  input_signature: (
    TensorSpec(shape=(1, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.uint8, name='input_tensor')).

Comment: Are you getting this error while loading or while doing the prediction?

Comment: Also, please edit your question and add your current attempt, so I can understand better what the problem is